# Hitting return terminates 2 scanf("%[^\n]%*c")

Tags: c, string, scanf, c99

I am trying to read 2 lines of user's input. For the first sequence, if I type in nothing and just hit return key, the program the prints `enter the second sequence` but not allowing the second `scanf`. Basically the return just terminates both `scanf`, resulting in both `str1` and `str2` empty.

```
printf("enter the first sequence: ");
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str1);

printf("enter the second sequence: ");
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str2);
```

Is there any way that I can fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The format specifier for strings is `%s`, so just use this instead:

```
printf("enter the first sequence: ");
scanf("\n%s", str1);

printf("enter the second sequence: ");
scanf("\n%s", str2);
```

As @AjayBrahmakshatriya commented: `\n` matches any number of `\n` characters.

The problem with `%c` when reading char with scanf is that it treats the newline as input, as I explained in this [example](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/).

---

However, if I were you, I'd just use [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), like this:

```
fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), stdin);
fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), stdin);
```

If you go with this approach, you will then probably be interested in [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)?